# An undefined volume appears out of nowhere?

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, mount

Today, I noticed another mounted volume on my computer:

[image]

This volume is the **size of my whole hard disk**. I can *only* see it in the iStat widget. I cannot see it in Finder or the Terminal.

```
$diskutil list
/dev/disk0
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *128.0 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            127.2 GB   disk0s2
3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

The name seems as if it is an encrypted volume. However, I don't have anything encrypted on this Mac.

- Where is this from?

(I hope this is not a bug of iStat Pro which showed me this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`diskutil list` will show you all the Lion core storage volumes and might be of use. The `df` command shows more network mounted volumes and will probably allow you to match that long string of characters to the storage structure used for MobileBackups in time machine.

```
mac:~ mike$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS mac                     499.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *1.8 MB     disk1
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Google Chrome 17.0.9... 1.7 MB     disk1s2
mac:~ mike$ df
Filesystem                        512-blocks      Used Available Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2                       975093952 837212344 137369608    86%    /
devfs                                    366       366         0   100%    /dev
map -hosts                                 0         0         0   100%    /net
map auto_home                              0         0         0   100%    /home
/dev/disk1s2                            3412      3412         0   100%    /private/tmp/UpdateEngine-mount.yzrVRXvfxf
localhost:/J91gqbWGFXawS6VmjrAKYp  975093952 975093952         0   100%    /Volumes/MobileBackups
```

Comment: This volume does not appear when using this command. :(

Comment: Oh well. After a reboot, I've checked the volume again. It  changed it's name to [MobileBackups](http://d.pr/rWSs) like you assumed. :)